# Multiple Checkbox transfer in 1 Row without overlapping

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I'm currently creating a reporting tool I have a problem with regards in exporting the details from User form to my Database (Sheet1).

Scenario:
What if the user checked multiple checkboxes in the user form, how will it transfer the data from multiple checkboxes to 1 row "G2" without overlapping? I'm using a command button to transfer the data to the empty cell

Sample UserForm:

[image: snapshot]

@ Mike

[Sample WorkSheet of Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15vOD.png)

Comment: Are you asking what happens when the user checks both boxes? Can you show us what you wold like the end result to look like?

Comment: @Mike I had a userform that has multiple checkbox if ever the user click the submit button all checked box will be transfer to specific column without overlapping to each other.

Comment: I attached the sample UserForm. Thank you,

Comment: That looks good. Can you post a sample of what you are expecting it to look like when a user checks two or three boxes? and Post the code where you are collecting the values and adding it to the specified cell?

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
.Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = "Unable to remove footer"
Else
.Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = ""


If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
.Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = "Unable to use PMSectionHead as First Level header/section"
Else
.Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = ""
End If
End If

End With
End Sub

Comment: You could have put that code into your question so that it would be formatted better in a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that might work then is this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

    RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
            .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value & vbCrLf & "Unable to remove footer"
        Else:
            .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = ""
        End If
        If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
            .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value & vbCrLf & "Unable to use PMSectionHead as First Level header/section"
        Else:
            .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I have it adding to the value that is already in the cell and putting a newline before each new value that is added. Then you will probably have to add an `If` for each `checkbox` since you are manually adding a string.

You need to check each one to see if more than one `checkbox` is checked. If you have them in an `If ... ElseIf` statement it will stop after the first true statement and not check all the rest.

**EDIT**

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim RowCounter
    RowCounter = 0

    RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
            .Offset(RowCount + RowCounter, 6).Value = .Offset(RowCount + RowCounter, 6).Value & vbCrLf & "Unable to remove footer"
            RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
        Else:
            .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = ""
        End If
        If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
            .Offset(RowCount + RowCounter, 6).Value = .Offset(RowCount + RowCounter, 6).Value & vbCrLf & "Unable to use PMSectionHead as First Level header/section"
            RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
        Else:
            .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I added a counter to the sub that will count if any of the checkboxes have been checked and go that many rows down starting with 0 rows down for 1 box checked. Not entirely sure that is what you were looking for, but I think it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I have some issue when I check both checkbox1 and checkbox 2 they appear both on the same Row (G2), I want them to be separated on different Row, the Checkbox 1 should be under G2 the Checkbox 2 is under Row G3 if they are both selected by the user. Much appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Yes It's working if I checked both checkbox, but if I only chose 1 check box it does not appear in rows. Thank you for your help, much appreciate!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean *it does not appear in rows*?

Comment: The above code is great but if i tried to check the checkbox1 it doesnt appear in worksheet but if i check the two checkboxes it shows in worksheet perfectly. Thanks and sorry to confuse you.